# Reconfiguring C++ code to deal with `warning: unsequenced modification and access to parameter`

Tags: c++, refactoring, warnings

I have several lines of code in a library I am compiling which are throwing warnings under clang (on OSX) like so:

```
warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'tmp' [-Wunsequenced]
    float tmp, fCosSqr = (tmp = cos(m_angle)) * tmp;
                              ^                 ~~~
```

This line of code looks pretty nasty and I'm finding it hard to be absolutely certain of what is going on.

As far as I can see, the final value of `fCosSqr` is supposed to be `cos(m_angle)^2`, and the final value of `tmp` is supposed to be `cos(m_angle)` (although in fact `tmp` is not  used anywhere else in the program.)

Presumably the warning is provided because if the assignments were done out of sequence, the unintialised value of `tmp` could be used instead of `cos(m_angle)`.

---

Could I rewrite the line of code as follows:

```
float tmp = cos(m_angle), fCosSqr = tmp * tmp;
```

or like so:

```
float fCosSqr = cos(m_angle) * cos(m_angle);
```

?

Why was the code ever written as it was? Is it supposed to provide some kind of speed gain?

Comment: Another possibility is a (inline) function, `float fCosSqr = square(cos(m_angle));`. Then there's no need for a named temporary.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good reason to write the code as it was. Just correct it and make a harsh complain to whoever wrote it in the first place. That and make sure to review any similar broken code from that same developer, as the library may be riddled with bugs like that one.

---

Note, the second approach that you provide might incur some additional cost. Unless the compiler can prove that `cos` is a pure function (i.e. multiple requests with the same arguments will yield the same exact result) it will have to call `cos` twice. Adding the temporary to hold the intermediate value is good, defining multiple variables in the same line is not so good, the undefined behavior in the original code is a horrible choice.